# The with_loader_criteria is not filtering out correctly in a join dominated query

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 4 models (A,B,C,D), all of which do not have the mixin class inherited on which the do_orm_Execute gets called and filters out the active rows. On joining these four, the rows that were expected to be filtered out, came in results.
Eg : A B C D are all linked with foreign keys. C and D have is_active = False for that particular foreign key reference, while A and B have is_active as True.

Rows not filtering out with with_loader_criteria

Main function to filter out is_active rows

```
def _do_orm_execute(execute_state):
    """Intercept all ORM queries.   Add a with_loader_criteria option to all
    of them.

    This option applies to SELECT queries and adds a global WHERE criteria
    (or as appropriate ON CLAUSE criteria for join targets)
    to all objects of a certain class or superclass.

    """

    # Incase you want to include rows with is_active=False, use execution_options(include_private=True) in query

    if not any((
            (execute_state.is_column_load),
            (execute_state.is_relationship_load),
            (execute_state.execution_options.get("include_private", False)))):
        execute_state.statement = execute_state.statement.options(
            orm.with_loader_criteria(
                MiscBaseMixin,
                lambda cls: cls.is_active == true(),
                include_aliases=True,
            )
        )
```

Now I have the 4 models in a query like this

`````
data_getter_query = session.query(A.a_id.label('a_ref'),
                                      B.b_id,
                                      C.c_id). \
        join(D, D.d_id == A.d_id). \
        join(B, B.b_id == D.b_id, isouter=True). \
        join(C, C.c_id == B.c_id, isouter=True). \
        filter(A.dt_created.isnot(None),
               A.pan_number == pan_number)
    ````
`````

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @snakecharmerb done, check now